# Bash find line number

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script:

```
find . -name "$2" -print | xargs grep --colour=auto "$1"
```

It searches for a $1 word in $2 matching files. How can I make it print the line number on which the word has been found.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use `find` and `xargs` here. You can use recursive grep like this:

```
grep -RHn --colour=auto "$1" --include='$2' .
```

**Options:**

```
-n  # for printing line numbers
-R  # for recursive grep
-H  # for printing file names
```

Comment: `--include` is a GNU-ism. The `find` approach is probably better when trying to be POSIX compatible.

Comment: Good point but as OP tagged `Linux` I would believe that gnu-grep is available.

Comment: Sure, available to them, but maybe not the next reader. That's why I'm so dogged about these things.

Comment: Yes I understand your point but all these answers are for the specific question asked. e.g. if OP tags a question as `bash` there is little point in making answer also compatible with ksh or bourne shells etc.

Comment: Considering most users of the bash tag don't know the difference between a shell and a terminal I think it's reasonable for experts not to assume the OP actually understands the scope of a tag.

Comment: Piping the output of `find` to `xargs` has its own problems which cannot be solved in a POSIX-compliant fashion.

Comment: Also, the presence of `--color` implies GNU `grep` (or at least something more featureful than POSIX).

Answer (score 4):

From `man grep`:

```
-n, --line-number
     Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.  (-n is specified by POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the line number of the word 'regex', to get only the line numbers, you could use

```
grep -n 'regex' | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\):.*$/\1/'
```

Or you could simply use sed:

```
sed -n '/regex/=' file_name
```

Comment: How could your second solution be used? When I use `sed -n "/regex/=WORDIMLOOKINGFOR" /path/to/file` I get the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 9: extra characters after command`

Comment: You got it mixed up, it's `sed -n '/WORDIMLOOKINGFOR/=' /path/to/file`. I still don't understand how it works, but it does work.